# Vertical alignment with prftree, tikz and beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, spacing, color, vertical-alignment

If you compile the following code, you can notice that transitioning from slide 1 to slide 2 causes the pre-existing figure in slide 1 to slightly move upwards. I'd like to keep it fixed in place, avoiding any perceptible shift in its position. I've tried with hphantom, vhantom and similar tools, but this is the best I've managed to achieve. I'm guessing the different spacing is due to the noline command in slide 1, so there might be some way to get around this by keeping the line and coloring it white, or manually adding the missing vertical space, but I don't know how to do either.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{prftree}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \uncover<1>{
            \draw (0,0) node {$\prftree[r,noline]{\hphantom{$\scriptstyle (\otimes)$}} {\prfsummary[$\!\Pi_1$]{\vdash \Gamma,A}} {\prfsummary[$\!\Pi_2$]{\vdash \Delta,B}} {}$};
        }
        \uncover<2->{
            \draw (0,0) node {$\prftree[r]{$\scriptstyle (\otimes)$} {\prfsummary[$\!\Pi_1$]{\vdash \Gamma,A}} {\prfsummary[$\!\Pi_2$]{\vdash \Delta,B}} {\vdash \Gamma,\Delta,A \otimes B}$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiling it with PDFLaTeX, I can only see the vertical dots changing their position, but very slightly.

Comment: Well, it would be nice to avoid this. I also wanted to add that I'm putting the derivation tree in a tikzpicture environment since in the original document there are other objects in there. I've removed them here since they did not change the spacing issue and I know that I should provide you with a *minimal* code.

Comment: I got a satisfying result by moving the node from (0,0) to (0,0.01). If I had found out sooner I wouldn't have asked, however one of the vertical dots still moves a bit even with this attempt, so it's not perfect and it may be interesting to see whether or not someone manages to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed right, the problem is that the first frame does not have the line.

The line thickness should be `\prflinethickness`, plus a pad of `\prflinepadbefore` before and `\prflinepadafter` after.

I tried adding a rule with no dimension and with a height below the baseline of `\prflinethickness+\prflinepadbefore+\prflinepadafter` but it is still not correct. After some trial and errors I found this solution:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{prftree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\prflinethickness}
\addtolength{\mylen}{\prflinepadbefore}
%\addtolength{\mylen}{\prflinepadafter}
\addtolength{\mylen}{.2ex}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \uncover<1>{%
            \node  {$\prftree[r,noline]{\phantom{$\scriptstyle (\otimes)$}}{\prfsummary[$\!\Pi_1$]{\vdash \Gamma,A}}{\prfsummary[$\!\Pi_2$]{\vdash \Delta,B\text{\rule[-\mylen]
            {0pt}{0pt}}}}{}$};%
        }
        \uncover<2->{%
            \node {$\prftree[r]{$\scriptstyle (\otimes)$}{\prfsummary[$\!\Pi_1$]{\vdash \Gamma,A}}{\prfsummary[$\!\Pi_2$]{\vdash \Delta,B}}{\vdash \Gamma,\Delta,A \otimes B}$};%
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now they seem perfectly aligned (the red lines here are, of course, added only to show the alignment between the two frames):

[image]